# Accessing the id of a recently created record & allowing for duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I'm having trouble with `has_many` `through:` models.

What I'd like to do is create 2 person chat rooms in my model. Therefore, users `has_many` chats and `has_many` messages through chats.

How do I access a recently created id and also allow for that id to be non-unique? Also, do I have the right setup for what I am trying to do?

```
@u = User.find_by_id(1)
@u.chats.new.save <--How to get this chat id to associate with another user id?
```

my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :chats
    has_many :messages, through: :chats
end

class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :message
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :chats
    has_many :users, through: :chats
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough one - we have implemented something similar recently using the following setup:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    #Chats
    def messages
        Chat.where("user_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?", id, id) # -> allows you to call @user.chats.sent to retrieve sent messages
    end
end

#app/models/chat.rb #- > id, user_id, recipient_id, message, read_at, created_at, updated_at
Class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "recipient_id"

    #Read
    scope :unread,  ->(type) { where("read_at IS #{type} NULL") }
    scope :read,    ->       { unread("NOT") }

    #Sent
    scope :sent,     -> { where(user_id: id) }
    scope :received, -> { where(recipient_id: id) }
end
```

This setup makes every `chat` "owned" by a particular user. This is done when you create a message, and represents the `sender`. Every message has a single `recipient`, which you can see with `recipient_id`

So you'll be able to send new messages to users like this:

```
@chat = Chat.new(chat_params)

def chat_params
   params.require(:chat).permit(:user_id, :recipient_id, :message)
end
```

This will be okay for a single chat room (I.E single message transcript between two users -- private messaging etc).

---

Can you explain how your chat rooms need to work? For example, if you only have two-way chats, surely you can use my above code? However, I feel it's not right; and I therefore want to refactor or you to accommodate multiple chat rooms

Comment: Ahhh I can `belongs_to` the same class twice? Awesome...This looks like a good start. Thank you! Regarding how my chat will work, I'm aiming for each person can have many 1 on 1 chats with other people. The actual chats are on mobile and this is my server side. Chats can be empty as I can start a chat with someone and not actually send any messages. This looks like it will be able to do that as well. Is there any difference from what you've implemented and having the chat be a join table that `has_many` messages?

Comment: Sounds like you're really talking about private messaging? If you're always going to be sending messages to other users, those messages will perpetually be in a single conversation. The difference between what I've got & having a join table is a join table would give you the flexibility to have multiple users per chat. My setup is facebook-type "one-to-one" messages, whilst a more extensible system would require the join model I thkn

Comment: Yea I guess I am talking about private messaging. This looks great I'll accept your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but this should give you your desired results.

```
@u = User.find(1) # You can use "find" instead of "find_by_id"
(@chat = @u.chats.new).save
@chat.users << User.find(x) # However you want to get the other user in the chat
```